# Preventing BeautifulSoup from converting my XML tags to lowercase

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulStoneSoup to parse an XML document and change some attributes. I noticed that it automatically converts all XML tags to lowercase. For example, my source file has `<DocData>` elements, which BeautifulSoup converts to `<docdata>`.

This appears to be causing problems since the program I am feeding my modified XML document to does not seem to accept the lowercase versions. Is there a way to prevent this behavior in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: See answers to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891690/can-i-change-beautifulsoups-behavior-regarding-converting-xml-tags-to-lowercase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not a built-in option. The source is pretty straightforward, though. It looks like you want to change the value of encodedName in Tag.`__str__.`

Answer (score 4):

- Simple Answer

  - change (default `html.parser`) to **xml** parser

    - code: `soup = BeautifulSoup(yourXmlStr, 'xml')`
- Detailed Explanation

  - refer [my answer in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891690/can-i-change-beautifulsoups-behavior-regarding-converting-xml-tags-to-lowercase/60719967#60719967)