# Can I change BeautifulSoup's behavior regarding converting XML tags to lowercase?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I'm working on code to parse a configuration file written in XML, where the XML tags are mixed case and the case is significant.  Beautiful Soup appears to convert XML tags to lowercase by default, and I would like to change this behavior.

I'm not the first to ask a question on this subject [see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/567999/preventing-beautifulsoup-from-converting-my-xml-tags-to-lowercase)].  However, I did not understand the answer given to that question and in BeautifulSoup-3.1.0.1 BeautifulSoup.py does not appear to contain any instances of "`encodedName`" or "`Tag.__str__`"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Leonard Richardson, creator|maintainer of Beautiful Soup, you [can't](http://groups.google.com/group/beautifulsoup/browse_thread/thread/ff6910752566df78).

Comment: [beautifulsoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) uses lxml to parse xml. It can use html5lib to parse html. These parsers should preserve the case of tags.

Answer (score 7):

```
import html5lib
from html5lib import treebuilders

f = open("mydocument.html")
parser = html5lib.XMLParser(tree=treebuilders.getTreeBuilder("beautifulsoup"))
document = parser.parse(f)
```

'document' is now a BeautifulSoup-like tree, but retains the cases of tags. See [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) for documentation and installation.

Answer (score 4):

## Background and Reason

first we should know: html parser is case-insensitive so convert tag to lowercase

and: `Beautifulsoup` internally call some `parser` to parse input `html`/`xml`.

-> for latest `bs4`=`BeautifulSoup v4`, default use `html.parer`.

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(yourXmlStr, 'html.parser')
```

but **ALL** `html parser` is case-insensitive, so `html.parer`

( and other two, say in [official doc](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

- `lxml`

  - `BeautifulSoup(yourHtmlOrXmlStr, "lxml")`
- `html5lib`

  - `BeautifulSoup(yourHtmlOrXmlStr, "html5lib")`

), will convert **TAG** to lowercase **tag**

## Example

- input:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<XCUIElementTypeApplication type="XCUIElementTypeApplication" name="微信"
    label="微信" enabled="true" visible="true" x="0" y="0" width="375" height="667">
    <XCUIElementTypeWindow
            type="XCUIElementTypeWindow" enabled="true" visible="true" x="0" y="0" width="375" height="667">
    </XCUIElementTypeWindow>
</XCUIElementTypeApplication>
```

- output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xcuielementtypeapplication enabled="true" height="667" label="微信" name="微信" type="XCUIElementTypeApplication" visible="true" width="375" x="0" y="0">
    <xcuielementtypewindow enabled="true" height="667" type="XCUIElementTypeWindow" visible="true" width="375" x="0" y="0">
    </xcuielementtypewindow>
    </xcuielementtypeapplication>
```

## How `disable` BeautifulSoup  tag-auto-lowercase-convertion ?

- Solution: change to **xml** parser
- Reason: **xml** parser support tag case-sensitive

  - -> not auto convert tag to all lowercase
- Code

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(yourXmlStr, 'xml')
```

same as:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(yourXmlStr, 'lxml-xml')
```

- output example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <XCUIElementTypeApplication enabled="true" height="667" label="微信" name="微信" type="XCUIElementTypeApplication" visible="true" width="375" x="0" y="0">
    <XCUIElementTypeWindow enabled="true" height="667" type="XCUIElementTypeWindow" visible="true" width="375" x="0" y="0">
    </XCUIElementTypeWindow>
    </XCUIElementTypeApplication>
```

## More detail

please refer my (Chinese) post: [【已解决】Python的BeautifulSoup中XML标签tag为何会自动被转换成小写以及是否可以禁止](http://www.crifan.com/python_beautifulsoup_xml_tag_converted_lowercase_why_and_how_disable_it)

Comment: Add one reminder: the attribute value in the HTML tag will not be converted into lower cases, only the HTML tags and their attribute name will be converted into lower cases. For example in `<p datatype="1" Name="Succeed" value="1"/>`, `Name` will be converted into lower cases but `Succeed` will not.

Answer (score 1):

It's much better to use [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/). It's much, much faster than BeautifulSoup. It has a compatibility API for BeautifulSoup too if you don't want to learn the lxml API.

[Ian Blicking agrees](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/).

There's no reason to use BeautifulSoup anymore, unless you're on Google App Engine or something where anything not purely Python isn't allowed.

It's more suited for XML as well.

Answer (score 0):

just use a propper xml parser instead of a lib thats made to deal with broken files

i suggest to just take a look at xml.etree or lxml